# Why doesn't Power BI recognize my R output as an excel document?

Tags: r, excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, openxlsx

I use the following function from the openxlsx package to export my dataframe to a local folder as an xlsx file:

```
write.xlsx(data frame, path, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I want to pull it into a Power BI project, but when I do, I get the following error from Power BI:
"The input couldn't be recognized as a valid Excel document."

But when I go into the file, save it and close, it then works fine.

Thank you

Comment: Most likely it's because of this bug in `openxlsx`: https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/231. I'm about to fix this in `openxlsx2`, but it's not simple and I do not have access to Power BI.

Comment: The same issue is occuring when reading data into Excel with the "Data" --> "Get Data" option (which reads the data via PowerQuery), maybe that helps when PowerBI is not accessible?